# リストアイテムに付けたししたい場合(.Addではなく)

Tags: c#

C#の構文の質問です。リストボックスについてのforeach文で、各アイテムに数字（stringに変換した変数）を付けたししたい場合、.Insertではうまくいかないようです。何がいけないのでしょうか。他にいい方法はありますでしょうか？（※一つのアイテムの中に付けたしたいので、.Addではないです。）

```
foreach(string item in names)
{
    NameList.Items.Insert(numbers);
}
```

Comment: .Insertも結局個別のアイテムとして追加されることになりそうですね…。

Comment: 「元のリスト」と「付け足した後のリスト」の例を質問文に含めてもらうとイメージしやすくなるかもしれません。 / 元が`リンゴ`, `バナナ`だったら`1リンゴ`, `2バナナ`になる？

Comment: 例えばですが、フルーツが10個あったとします（個数はテキストボックスによる入力値です）。リストボックスには、ドラえもん 、のびた、しずか　などのように名前があります。そのリストボックス上のメンバーでフルーツを平等に分配するということがしたいです。この場合は、10/3となるので、各人が３個ずつ分け与えられることになります。最終的にリストボックス上にドラえもん:3、のびた:3、しずか:3という具合に数字を追加しようとしています。

Answer (score 2):

これは単純に配列としてアクセスすれば良いでしょう。

```
int fruits = 10;
int listcount = NameList.Items.Count;
int quotient = fruits / listcount;
for (int i=0; i<listcount; i++)
{
    NameList.Items[i] += ":" + quotient.ToString();
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。なるほど！